# insert VBA code in existing macro to change listrows property

Tags: excel, vba

I am using following macro to insert multiple combobox into spreadsheet

```
Sub Macro4()

    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    With ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
             .Delete   ' delete all objects


        For i = 0 To 0
            For j = 0 To 10
               .Add ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1", _
                    Left:=i * 280 + 261, _
                    Top:=(j * 15) + 0, _
                    Width:=275, _
                    Height:=15, _
                    Link:=False, _
                    DisplayAsIcon:=False

                .Item(i * 10 + j + 1).LinkedCell = "G" & i * 10 + j + 1
                .Item(i * 10 + j + 1).ListFillRange = "test1"


            Next j
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

sadly I am not the author and I have 0 VBA competences hence I have no idea how to make it happen that default listrows parameter would be 60.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to create 60 combo boxes, the following will work:

```
Sub Macro4()

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
With ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
         .Delete   ' delete all objects


    For i = 0 To 0
        For j = 0 To 60
           .Add ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1", _
                Left:=i * 280 + 261, _
                Top:=(j * 15) + 0, _
                Width:=275, _
                Height:=15, _
                Link:=False, _
                DisplayAsIcon:=False

            .Item(i * 10 + j + 1).LinkedCell = "G" & i * 10 + j + 1
            .Item(i * 10 + j + 1).ListFillRange = "test1"


        Next j
    Next i
End With
```

End Sub

If you are looking for 60 boxes with 10 in each column the following will work:

```
Sub Macro4()

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
With ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
         .Delete   ' delete all objects


    For i = 0 To 6
        For j = 0 To 10
           .Add ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1", _
                Left:=i * 280 + 261, _
                Top:=(j * 15) + 0, _
                Width:=275, _
                Height:=15, _
                Link:=False, _
                DisplayAsIcon:=False

            .Item(i * 10 + j + 1).LinkedCell = "G" & i * 10 + j + 1
            .Item(i * 10 + j + 1).ListFillRange = "test1"


        Next j
    Next i
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: I am assuming when you say you want default list rows to be 60, it is the number of rows created.